# BMP File to PNG File Converter

Tags: png, bmp

I'm making a BMP to PNG Converter.
The BMP Images are uncompressed.

So my question is when the BMP File is converted to a PNG File, then is the PNG File compressed i.e is the image data compressed. If so how is the image data aligned in the PNG File Format?

If the PNG Image Data is uncompressed then how is the BMP Image Data Aligned in PNG File.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#pragma pack(1)
typedef struct
{
        unsigned short int  st_m40_FileType;

        unsigned int        st_m40_ImgFileSize;

        unsigned short int  st_m40_RsvdBytes1;

        unsigned short int  st_m40_RsvdBytes2;

        unsigned int        st_m40_ImgDataOffset;

        unsigned int        st_m40_Info40HeaderSze;

        int         st_m40_PxWdth;

        int         st_m40_PxHeight;

        unsigned short int  st_m40_NumOfColrPlnes;

        unsigned short int  st_m40_BitsPerPixel;

        unsigned int        st_m40_CmprsnType;

        unsigned int        st_m40_AftrCmprsnImgDataSze;

        int         st_m40_xResolutn_ppm;

        int         st_m40_yResolutn_ppm;

        unsigned int        st_m40_NumOfColrTbleColrs;

        unsigned int        st_m40_NumOfImprtntColrs;

}ST_BMP40HEADER_t;

typedef struct 
{

        ST_BMP40HEADER_t    st_mBMP40MainHdrVar;

        unsigned char *     pst_mImgeData;

}ST_IMAGE_40_HEADER_t;


typedef enum
{
        BI_RGB = 0x00,
        BI_RLE8,
        BI_RLE4,
        BI_BITFIELDS,
        BI_JPEG,
        BI_PNG,
        BI_ALPHABITFIELDS,
        BI_CMYK,
        BI_CMYKRLE8,
        BI_CMYKRLE4,

}EN_BMP_COMPRESN_TYPE_t;

#pragma pack(1)
typedef struct 
{
        int         st_mImgWdth;
        int         st_ImgHeight;
        unsigned char   st_mBitDepth;
        unsigned char   st_mColorType;
        unsigned char   st_mCmprsnMthd;
        unsigned char   st_mFltrMthd;
        unsigned char   st_mInterlaceMthd;

}ST_IHDR_DATA_FIELDS_t;

#pragma pack(1)
typedef struct 
{
        unsigned int    st_mChunkDataLngth;
        unsigned char   st_mChunkType[4];
        ST_IHDR_DATA_FIELDS_t       st_IHDR_DataFieldsVar;
        unsigned int    st_mCRC32CheckSum;

}ST_IHDR_t;

#pragma pack(1)
typedef struct
{
        unsigned int        st_mPLTE_ChunkDataLngth;
        unsigned char       st_mPLTE_ChunkType[4];
        unsigned char*      st_mPLTE_ChunkDataPtr;
        unsigned int        st_mPLTE_CRC32CheckSum;

}ST_PLTE_t;

#pragma pack(1)
typedef struct
{
        unsigned int        st_mIDAT_ChunkDataLngth;
        unsigned char       st_mIDAT_ChunkType[4];
        unsigned char*      st_mIDAT_ChunkDataPtr;
        unsigned int        st_mIDAT_CRC32CheckSum;

}ST_IDAT_t;

#pragma pack(1)
typedef struct
{
        unsigned int        st_mIEND_ChunkDataLength;
        unsigned char       st_mIEND_ChunkType[4];
        unsigned char *     st_mIEND_ChunkDataPtr;
        unsigned int        st_mIEND_CRC32CheckSum;

}ST_IEND_t;

/* Little Endian to Big-Endian API. */
unsigned int BMP2PNG_LitToBigEndian(unsigned int f_BigEndianVal)
{
    return (((f_BigEndianVal>>24) & 0x000000ff) | ((f_BigEndianVal>>8) & 0x0000ff00) |\
                         ((f_BigEndianVal<<8) & 0x00ff0000) | ((f_BigEndianVal<<24) & 0xff000000));
}

/* CRC32 API.*/
unsigned int BMP2PNG_CmputeCRC32(unsigned char *p_fIpVal, unsigned int f_IpSize) 
{
        int l_LoopVar;
        unsigned int l_ByteVal, l_CRCVal, l_MaskVal;
        unsigned int l_TmpIncVar = 0;


        l_CRCVal = 0xFFFFFFFF;

        while (l_TmpIncVar <= f_IpSize) 
        {
            // Get next byte.
            l_ByteVal = p_fIpVal[l_TmpIncVar];
            l_CRCVal = l_CRCVal ^ l_ByteVal;

            for (l_LoopVar = 7; l_LoopVar >= 0; l_LoopVar--) 
            {
                // Do eight times.
                l_MaskVal = -(l_CRCVal & 1);
                l_CRCVal = (l_CRCVal >> 1) ^ (0xEDB88320 & l_MaskVal);
            }

            l_TmpIncVar = l_TmpIncVar + 1;
        }

        return ~l_CRCVal;
}

/* API converts BMP-to-PNG format. */
char *  Convert__40_BMP2PNG(ST_IMAGE_40_HEADER_t * pst_fBMP40ImgHdrVar, FILE * p_ImgFilePtr,\
                                                                    unsigned char * p_fBMP_ColrTble)
{
        FILE *          l_BMP2PNGFilePtr;

        ST_IHDR_t *     pst_lIHDRChunkVar;

        unsigned char l_PNGSignature[8]={137, 80, 78, 71, 13, 10, 26, 10};
        unsigned int l_BigEndianVal;

        unsigned int l_CRC32Val;
        unsigned char * l_TempCRCBuff;
        unsigned char * l_CRCBuffer;
        unsigned int l_BuffLength = 0;

        unsigned int l_TempIHDRChunkDataLngth;

        pst_lIHDRChunkVar = (ST_IHDR_t *) malloc(sizeof(*pst_lIHDRChunkVar));

        l_BMP2PNGFilePtr = fopen("BMP2PNG2.png","w");

        /* Writing the 1st 8-bytes to the PNG File.*/
        fwrite(l_PNGSignature,1,8,l_BMP2PNGFilePtr);

        fseek(l_BMP2PNGFilePtr,8,SEEK_SET);

        pst_lIHDRChunkVar->st_mChunkDataLngth = 13;

        l_TempIHDRChunkDataLngth = BMP2PNG_LitToBigEndian(13);

        /*Writing the IHDR Chunk Data-Length-Size value to the file.*/
        fwrite(&l_TempIHDRChunkDataLngth,sizeof(unsigned int),1,l_BMP2PNGFilePtr);

        pst_lIHDRChunkVar->st_mChunkType[0] = 'I';
        pst_lIHDRChunkVar->st_mChunkType[1] = 'H';
        pst_lIHDRChunkVar->st_mChunkType[2] = 'D';
        pst_lIHDRChunkVar->st_mChunkType[3] = 'R';

        /* Writing the IHDR-Chunk-Type value to the file.*/
        fwrite( pst_lIHDRChunkVar->st_mChunkType ,sizeof(unsigned char),4,l_BMP2PNGFilePtr);

//      pst_lIHDRChunkVar->st_IHDR_DataFieldsVar.st_mImgWdth = BMP2PNG_LitToBigEndian(pst_fBMP40ImgHdrVar->st_mBMP40MainHdrVar.st_m40_PxWdth);
        pst_lIHDRChunkVar->st_IHDR_DataFieldsVar.st_mImgWdth = BMP2PNG_LitToBigEndian(3);

//      pst_lIHDRChunkVar->st_IHDR_DataFieldsVar.st_ImgHeight = BMP2PNG_LitToBigEndian(pst_fBMP40ImgHdrVar->st_mBMP40MainHdrVar.st_m40_PxHeight);
        pst_lIHDRChunkVar->st_IHDR_DataFieldsVar.st_ImgHeight = BMP2PNG_LitToBigEndian(3);

        if(pst_fBMP40ImgHdrVar->st_mBMP40MainHdrVar.st_m40_BitsPerPixel <= 8)
        {
            pst_lIHDRChunkVar->st_IHDR_DataFieldsVar.st_mBitDepth = pst_fBMP40ImgHdrVar->st_mBMP40MainHdrVar.st_m40_BitsPerPixel;
        }
        else if( (pst_fBMP40ImgHdrVar->st_mBMP40MainHdrVar.st_m40_BitsPerPixel == 24) || \
                                                (pst_fBMP40ImgHdrVar->st_mBMP40MainHdrVar.st_m40_BitsPerPixel == 32) )
        {
            pst_lIHDRChunkVar->st_IHDR_DataFieldsVar.st_mBitDepth = 8;
        }
        else
        {
            /*No Action.*/
        }


        if( pst_fBMP40ImgHdrVar->st_mBMP40MainHdrVar.st_m40_BitsPerPixel <=8 )
        {
            pst_lIHDRChunkVar->st_IHDR_DataFieldsVar.st_mColorType = 3;
        }
        else if (pst_fBMP40ImgHdrVar->st_mBMP40MainHdrVar.st_m40_BitsPerPixel == 24)
        {
            pst_lIHDRChunkVar->st_IHDR_DataFieldsVar.st_mColorType = 2;
        }
        else if (pst_fBMP40ImgHdrVar->st_mBMP40MainHdrVar.st_m40_BitsPerPixel == 32)
        {
            pst_lIHDRChunkVar->st_IHDR_DataFieldsVar.st_mColorType = 6;
        }
        else
        {
            /*No Action.*/
        }

        pst_lIHDRChunkVar->st_IHDR_DataFieldsVar.st_mCmprsnMthd = 0;
        pst_lIHDRChunkVar->st_IHDR_DataFieldsVar.st_mFltrMthd = 0;
        pst_lIHDRChunkVar->st_IHDR_DataFieldsVar.st_mInterlaceMthd = 0;

        fseek(l_BMP2PNGFilePtr,16,SEEK_SET);

        fwrite(&pst_lIHDRChunkVar->st_IHDR_DataFieldsVar,sizeof(ST_IHDR_DATA_FIELDS_t),1,l_BMP2PNGFilePtr);

        {
            /* Framing the data for calculating the 32-bit CRC Checksum.*/
            l_BuffLength = 4+(pst_lIHDRChunkVar->st_mChunkDataLngth);
            l_CRCBuffer = (unsigned char*)malloc(l_BuffLength);


            l_TempCRCBuff = l_CRCBuffer;
            *l_TempCRCBuff++ = pst_lIHDRChunkVar->st_mChunkType[0];
            *l_TempCRCBuff++ = pst_lIHDRChunkVar->st_mChunkType[1];
            *l_TempCRCBuff++ = pst_lIHDRChunkVar->st_mChunkType[2];
            *l_TempCRCBuff++ = pst_lIHDRChunkVar->st_mChunkType[3];

            *l_TempCRCBuff++ = (unsigned char)pst_lIHDRChunkVar->st_IHDR_DataFieldsVar.st_mImgWdth;
            *l_TempCRCBuff++ = (unsigned char)(pst_lIHDRChunkVar->st_IHDR_DataFieldsVar.st_mImgWdth << 8);
            *l_TempCRCBuff++ = (unsigned char)(pst_lIHDRChunkVar->st_IHDR_DataFieldsVar.st_mImgWdth << 16);
            *l_TempCRCBuff++ = (unsigned char)(pst_lIHDRChunkVar->st_IHDR_DataFieldsVar.st_mImgWdth << 24);

            *l_TempCRCBuff++ = (unsigned char)pst_lIHDRChunkVar->st_IHDR_DataFieldsVar.st_ImgHeight;
            *l_TempCRCBuff++ = (unsigned char)(pst_lIHDRChunkVar->st_IHDR_DataFieldsVar.st_ImgHeight << 8);
            *l_TempCRCBuff++ = (unsigned char)(pst_lIHDRChunkVar->st_IHDR_DataFieldsVar.st_ImgHeight << 16);
            *l_TempCRCBuff++ = (unsigned char)(pst_lIHDRChunkVar->st_IHDR_DataFieldsVar.st_ImgHeight << 24);

            *l_TempCRCBuff++ = (unsigned char)(pst_lIHDRChunkVar->st_IHDR_DataFieldsVar.st_mBitDepth);
            *l_TempCRCBuff++ = (unsigned char)(pst_lIHDRChunkVar->st_IHDR_DataFieldsVar.st_mColorType);
            *l_TempCRCBuff++ = (unsigned char)(pst_lIHDRChunkVar->st_IHDR_DataFieldsVar.st_mCmprsnMthd);
            *l_TempCRCBuff++ = (unsigned char)(pst_lIHDRChunkVar->st_IHDR_DataFieldsVar.st_mFltrMthd);
            *l_TempCRCBuff   = (unsigned char)(pst_lIHDRChunkVar->st_IHDR_DataFieldsVar.st_mInterlaceMthd);

            // Compute and output CRC
            l_CRC32Val = BMP2PNG_CmputeCRC32(l_CRCBuffer, l_BuffLength);
            l_CRC32Val = BMP2PNG_LitToBigEndian( l_CRC32Val);
            fseek(l_BMP2PNGFilePtr,29,SEEK_SET);

            unsigned int returnVal = fwrite(&l_CRC32Val,sizeof(unsigned int),1,l_BMP2PNGFilePtr);
        }

        unsigned char * p_lBMPImgData = pst_fBMP40ImgHdrVar->pst_mImgeData;
//      unsigned int l_BMPImgeDataSze =  ( (pst_fBMP40ImgHdrVar->st_mBMP40MainHdrVar.st_m40_PxWdth) * \
                                (pst_fBMP40ImgHdrVar->st_mBMP40MainHdrVar.st_m40_PxHeight) );

        unsigned int l_BMPImgeDataSze = (3*3)*3;

        ST_IDAT_t * pst_lIDAT_ChunkVar;
        pst_lIDAT_ChunkVar = (ST_IDAT_t *) malloc(sizeof(*pst_lIDAT_ChunkVar));

        unsigned int l_ImgDataSzeIncVar = 0;

        unsigned char * p_IDATBuf;

        unsigned char * p_TempIDATBuf;
        unsigned int l_IDATBufSze;

        if(pst_fBMP40ImgHdrVar->st_mBMP40MainHdrVar.st_m40_BitsPerPixel == 24)
        {
            fseek(l_BMP2PNGFilePtr,33,SEEK_SET);
            l_BMPImgeDataSze *= 3;

            l_IDATBufSze = 4 + l_BMPImgeDataSze;

            p_IDATBuf = (unsigned char*)malloc(l_IDATBufSze);

            p_TempIDATBuf = p_IDATBuf;

            pst_lIDAT_ChunkVar->st_mIDAT_ChunkDataLngth = BMP2PNG_LitToBigEndian(l_BMPImgeDataSze);

            fwrite(&pst_lIDAT_ChunkVar->st_mIDAT_ChunkDataLngth,sizeof(unsigned int),1,l_BMP2PNGFilePtr);

            pst_lIDAT_ChunkVar->st_mIDAT_ChunkType[0] = 'I';
            pst_lIDAT_ChunkVar->st_mIDAT_ChunkType[1] = 'D';
            pst_lIDAT_ChunkVar->st_mIDAT_ChunkType[2] = 'A';
            pst_lIDAT_ChunkVar->st_mIDAT_ChunkType[3] = 'T';

            fwrite( pst_lIDAT_ChunkVar->st_mIDAT_ChunkType ,sizeof(unsigned char),4,l_BMP2PNGFilePtr);

            fseek(l_BMP2PNGFilePtr,41,SEEK_SET);
            unsigned char ImgeData[27]  = { 0,255,0,0,255,0,0,255,0,0,255,0,0,255,0,0,255,0,0,255,0,0,255,0,0,255,0,};

            while(l_ImgDataSzeIncVar <= l_BMPImgeDataSze )
            {
                fwrite(ImgeData,sizeof(unsigned char),1,l_BMP2PNGFilePtr);
/*
                fwrite( (p_lBMPImgData+2),sizeof(unsigned char),1,l_BMP2PNGFilePtr);
                *p_TempIDATBuf++ = *(p_lBMPImgData+2);

                fwrite( (p_lBMPImgData+1),sizeof(unsigned char),1,l_BMP2PNGFilePtr);
                *p_TempIDATBuf++ = *(p_lBMPImgData+1);  

                fwrite( (p_lBMPImgData),sizeof(unsigned char),1,l_BMP2PNGFilePtr);
                *p_TempIDATBuf++ = *(p_lBMPImgData);

                p_lBMPImgData += 3;
                l_ImgDataSzeIncVar += 3;
*/
            }
        // Compute and output CRC
        unsigned int crc32 = BMP2PNG_CmputeCRC32(p_IDATBuf, l_IDATBufSze);
        fwrite(&crc32,sizeof(unsigned int),1,l_BMP2PNGFilePtr);


        }

}


ST_IMAGE_40_HEADER_t *  ReadBMP40HdrImage(ST_IMAGE_40_HEADER_t * pst_fBMP40ImgHdrVar, \
                                FILE * p_ImgFilePtr)
{
    unsigned short int  l_ColorTbleSze;
    unsigned char *     l_ColorTbleVal;

    unsigned int        l_ImageDataOffset;

    unsigned int        l_ImageDataSize;
    unsigned int        l_ImageDataSzeIncVar = 1;
    unsigned char *     l_ImageDataPtr;
    unsigned int        l_PixelCount = 1;

    int l_NumOfReadBlks = fread(pst_fBMP40ImgHdrVar,sizeof(pst_fBMP40ImgHdrVar->st_mBMP40MainHdrVar),1,p_ImgFilePtr);

    printf("\n********************************************************************\n");

    printf("\nPrinting the BMP Image Parameters:\n");

    printf("\nBMP File Header Parameters.\n");
    printf("File Type:\t'BM'\n");
    printf("Total Size of the image:\t%u\n",pst_fBMP40ImgHdrVar->st_mBMP40MainHdrVar.st_m40_ImgFileSize);
    printf("Image Data Offset:\t%u\n",pst_fBMP40ImgHdrVar->st_mBMP40MainHdrVar.st_m40_ImgDataOffset);

    printf("\nBMP Info Header Parameters.\n");
    printf("Size of the Info-Header:\t'%u-Bytes'.\n",pst_fBMP40ImgHdrVar->st_mBMP40MainHdrVar.st_m40_Info40HeaderSze);
    printf("Width of the BMP Image:\t'%d-Pixels'.\n",pst_fBMP40ImgHdrVar->st_mBMP40MainHdrVar.st_m40_PxWdth);
    printf("Height of the BMP Image:\t'%d-Pixels'.\n",pst_fBMP40ImgHdrVar->st_mBMP40MainHdrVar.st_m40_PxHeight);
    printf("Number of Color Planes:\t'%d'.\n",pst_fBMP40ImgHdrVar->st_mBMP40MainHdrVar.st_m40_NumOfColrPlnes);
    printf("Number of Bits-Per-Pixel:\t'%d'.\n",pst_fBMP40ImgHdrVar->st_mBMP40MainHdrVar.st_m40_BitsPerPixel);
    printf("Compression Type used for compressing the BMP Raw Image:\t'%d'.\n",\
                                            pst_fBMP40ImgHdrVar->st_mBMP40MainHdrVar.st_m40_CmprsnType);
    printf("Horizontal Resolution:\t'%d-Pixels Per Meter'.\n,",\
                                    pst_fBMP40ImgHdrVar->st_mBMP40MainHdrVar.st_m40_xResolutn_ppm);

    printf("Vertical Resolution:\t'%d-Pixels Per Meter'.\n,",\
                                    pst_fBMP40ImgHdrVar->st_mBMP40MainHdrVar.st_m40_yResolutn_ppm);

    if(pst_fBMP40ImgHdrVar->st_mBMP40MainHdrVar.st_m40_NumOfColrTbleColrs !=0 )
    {
        printf("Number of Colors in the color table:\t'%u'.\n",\
                            pst_fBMP40ImgHdrVar->st_mBMP40MainHdrVar.st_m40_NumOfColrTbleColrs);        
    }

    if( (pst_fBMP40ImgHdrVar->st_mBMP40MainHdrVar.st_m40_BitsPerPixel <= 8) && \
                (pst_fBMP40ImgHdrVar->st_mBMP40MainHdrVar.st_m40_NumOfColrTbleColrs !=0) )
    {
        rewind(p_ImgFilePtr);
        fseek(p_ImgFilePtr,55,SEEK_SET);

        l_ColorTbleSze = (pst_fBMP40ImgHdrVar->st_mBMP40MainHdrVar.st_m40_NumOfColrTbleColrs) * 4 ;
        l_ColorTbleVal = (unsigned char*) malloc( l_ColorTbleSze );
        l_NumOfReadBlks = fread(l_ColorTbleVal, l_ColorTbleSze, 1, p_ImgFilePtr);

        if(l_NumOfReadBlks <1)
        {
            printf("Couldn't read the Color-Table values from the BMP File.\n");
            return NULL;
        }
        else if(l_NumOfReadBlks == 1)
        {
            unsigned short int l_ClrTbleIncVar = 0;
            unsigned char * l_TempColorTbleVal = l_ColorTbleVal;
            unsigned short int l_IndexVal = 0;

            printf("\n*****************************************************************************\n");
            printf("Printing the color Table.\n");

            while (l_ClrTbleIncVar <= (l_ColorTbleSze-4) )
            {
                printf("Index   '%d' : ", l_IndexVal);
                printf("Blue    ->  '%d'\t",*l_TempColorTbleVal);
                l_TempColorTbleVal++;
                printf("Green   ->  '%d'\t",*l_TempColorTbleVal);
                l_TempColorTbleVal++;
                printf("Red     ->  '%d'\t\n",*l_TempColorTbleVal);
                l_TempColorTbleVal+=2;
                l_ClrTbleIncVar += 4;
                l_IndexVal++;
            }           
        }
    }

    rewind(p_ImgFilePtr);
    l_ImageDataOffset = pst_fBMP40ImgHdrVar->st_mBMP40MainHdrVar.st_m40_ImgDataOffset;
    fseek(p_ImgFilePtr,l_ImageDataOffset,SEEK_SET);

    if(pst_fBMP40ImgHdrVar->st_mBMP40MainHdrVar.st_m40_BitsPerPixel == 4)
    {
        l_ImageDataSize = ( (pst_fBMP40ImgHdrVar->st_mBMP40MainHdrVar.st_m40_PxWdth) * \
                                            (pst_fBMP40ImgHdrVar->st_mBMP40MainHdrVar.st_m40_PxHeight) )/2;

        pst_fBMP40ImgHdrVar->pst_mImgeData = (unsigned char*)malloc(l_ImageDataSize);

        l_ImageDataPtr = pst_fBMP40ImgHdrVar->pst_mImgeData;


        l_NumOfReadBlks = fread(l_ImageDataPtr,1,l_ImageDataSize,p_ImgFilePtr);

        if(l_NumOfReadBlks < 1)
        {
            printf("Couldn't read the image data from the file.\n");
            return NULL;
        }
    }

    else if(pst_fBMP40ImgHdrVar->st_mBMP40MainHdrVar.st_m40_BitsPerPixel == 8)
    {
        l_ImageDataSize = ( (pst_fBMP40ImgHdrVar->st_mBMP40MainHdrVar.st_m40_PxWdth) * \
                                            (pst_fBMP40ImgHdrVar->st_mBMP40MainHdrVar.st_m40_PxHeight) );

        pst_fBMP40ImgHdrVar->pst_mImgeData = (unsigned char*)malloc(l_ImageDataSize);

        l_ImageDataPtr = pst_fBMP40ImgHdrVar->pst_mImgeData;


        l_NumOfReadBlks = fread(l_ImageDataPtr,l_ImageDataSize,1,p_ImgFilePtr);

        if(l_NumOfReadBlks < 1)
        {
            printf("Couldn't read the image data from the file.\n");
            return NULL;
        }


    }

    else if(pst_fBMP40ImgHdrVar->st_mBMP40MainHdrVar.st_m40_BitsPerPixel == 24)
    {
        l_ImageDataSize = ( (pst_fBMP40ImgHdrVar->st_mBMP40MainHdrVar.st_m40_PxWdth) * \
                                            (pst_fBMP40ImgHdrVar->st_mBMP40MainHdrVar.st_m40_PxHeight) * 3 );

        pst_fBMP40ImgHdrVar->pst_mImgeData = (unsigned char*)malloc(l_ImageDataSize);

        l_ImageDataPtr = pst_fBMP40ImgHdrVar->pst_mImgeData;


        l_NumOfReadBlks = fread(l_ImageDataPtr,l_ImageDataSize,1,p_ImgFilePtr);

        if(l_NumOfReadBlks < 1)
        {
            printf("Couldn't read the image data from the file.\n");
            return NULL;
        }
    }
    else if(pst_fBMP40ImgHdrVar->st_mBMP40MainHdrVar.st_m40_BitsPerPixel == 32)
    {
        l_ImageDataSize = ( (pst_fBMP40ImgHdrVar->st_mBMP40MainHdrVar.st_m40_PxWdth) * \
                                            (pst_fBMP40ImgHdrVar->st_mBMP40MainHdrVar.st_m40_PxHeight) * 4 );

        pst_fBMP40ImgHdrVar->pst_mImgeData = (unsigned char*)malloc(l_ImageDataSize);

        l_ImageDataPtr = pst_fBMP40ImgHdrVar->pst_mImgeData;


        l_NumOfReadBlks = fread(l_ImageDataPtr,l_ImageDataSize,1,p_ImgFilePtr);

        if(l_NumOfReadBlks < 1)
        {
            printf("Couldn't read the image data from the file.\n");
            return NULL;
        }
    }

    rewind(p_ImgFilePtr);
    Convert__40_BMP2PNG(pst_fBMP40ImgHdrVar,p_ImgFilePtr,l_ColorTbleVal);

}

int main()
{
    FILE *      l_ImgeFilePtr;

    l_ImgeFilePtr = fopen("FLAG_B24.BMP","r");

    unsigned short int      l_ImgeFileType;

    unsigned int            l_InfoHdrSze;

    int l_NumofReadBlocks;

    l_NumofReadBlocks = fread(&l_ImgeFileType,2,1,l_ImgeFilePtr);

    if(l_NumofReadBlocks <1)
    {
        printf("Couldn't read the bytes from the file.\n");
        return 0;
    }


    if(l_ImgeFileType != 19778)
    {
        printf("Image Passed is not a BMP file.\n");
        return 0;
    }

    fseek(l_ImgeFilePtr,14,SEEK_SET);

    l_NumofReadBlocks = fread(&l_InfoHdrSze, 4, 1, l_ImgeFilePtr);

    if(l_NumofReadBlocks <1)
    {
        printf("Couldn't read the bytes from the file.\n");
        return 0;
    }


    rewind(l_ImgeFilePtr);
    if( l_InfoHdrSze == 40 )
    {
        ST_IMAGE_40_HEADER_t *      pst_Img40HdrVar;

        pst_Img40HdrVar = malloc(sizeof(*pst_Img40HdrVar));

        if(pst_Img40HdrVar == NULL)
        {
            printf("There isn't enough memory to allocate for the Image header variable.\n");
            return 0;
        }

        ST_IMAGE_40_HEADER_t * pst_l40_ReadAPIReturnVal = ReadBMP40HdrImage(pst_Img40HdrVar, l_ImgeFilePtr);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> is the PNG File compressed

Yes.

> how is the image data aligned in the PNG File Format?

It's not aligned. From the [spec](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/spec/iso/index-object.html), "The chunk data length may be any number of bytes up to the maximum; therefore, implementors cannot assume that chunks are aligned on any boundaries larger than bytes."

Multitudinous image handling libraries exist to save you from worrying about these details, though. I'd recommend against rolling your own converter unless your goal is specifically to learn about image file formats.

Comment: I have a same51 micontroller which is connected to a camera, which when clicks a picture stores it in a BMP file format and on the other side i have a display unit which displays a image of PNG file format. So i have to write the code without using libraries like libpng,etc. For this i have created a code to read the bmp file, assign the image parameters and the image to PNG chunks, which i have done. But the final output doesn't result out as a PNG image. I have attached the file with the code.